# Energy of a complex exponential signal

Tags: communication, digital-communications, homework

Noob question here. Why would the term \$j2\pi t\$ not have any effect on the energy of the signal?

[image: Complex Exponential Signal]

Comment: What's the magnitude of \$e^{2πjt}\$?

Comment: It’s bipolar reactive power thus zero net energy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply Euler’s formula. Hence

$$|e^{at + jbt}|^2 = |e^{at} e^{jbt}|^2 = |e^{at} [\cos(bt) + j \sin(b t)]|^2.$$

Thus

$$|e^{at + jbt}|^2 = e^{2at} [\cos^2(b t) + \sin^2(b t)] = e^{2at}.$$